# How to design a regex coding to adding % to a trade results. Take profit, stop loss, or even entry

Tags: javascript, python, regex, telegram-bot, algorithmic-trading

I have inquiry on my regex (bot). I’m stuck. I am trying to add percentage on my forex Signal. To increase or reduce my “take profit” (TP) and to increase or reduce my “stop loss” (SL).

Let’s imagine the signal is:

```
Signal :⬆️ BUY 
Price ENTRY: 0.73534 
TP1: 0.76639 
SL: 0.73415
```

(Simple right?) my last regex was:

```
/replacerx ⬆️&nbsp;BUY&nbsp;SL[0-9] SLs/~[0-9]*/$0,3%/g
```

If the signal was “SELL” so it will be

```
Signal :⬇️ SELL 
Price ENTRY: 0.73534 
TP1: 0.76639 
SL: 0.73415
```

My regex will be:

```
/replacerx ⬇️&nbsp;SELL&nbsp;SL[0-9] SLs/~[0-9]*/$-0,3%/g
```

But it failed again!

I identify (⬆️ BUY )or (⬇️ SELL) in regex and also “SL” Because the percentage need to change when it’s “SELL position” and not “BUY” and also when it’s “TP” and others. What can I try next?

Comment: What is `SL[0-9]` supposed to match? I don't see that after `BUY` and `SELL`

Comment: It’s just some coding that I rode about in other topic. 
The guy had multiple scenarios. to implement to DOT. I try them all. No one was working. This one was the last. It fall to. The SL [0-9] was to show the group “SL”  and [0-9] was to show the results numbers of the signal. I don’t know if this makes sense to you?

Comment: But he's obviously parsing different messages from you. You need to write a regexp that matches the messages you're processing, not use his regexp.

Comment: Understand brother. But I’m newbie 

Comment: This is why I was asking help

Comment: The guy put me in the track. Without giving me the right coding. I tried everything that I know. And this one (The one that I rode on my question) what is the last coding that I thought was correct. But I guess I was wrong. again

Comment: Seems like you're asking for us to do it for you, because it doesn't look like you've made any attempt to solve it yourself (other than just copying code that's obviously not related).

Comment: Programming is not paint-by-numbers, you can't expect to find pre-written code that does it. You have to learn to write it yourself, not just copy.

Comment: Read the tutorial at regular-expression.info

Comment: Barmar, I am not try to copy anybody. I am not trying to ask anyone to do my homework. I thought I can find some help in this site. I don’t know how to do any coding. I don’t know JavaScript, Pythons or any other coding. I am not in computer industry at all. I tried to make money in trading Industry. So I purchase software. It’s like a Scaner. Unfortunately the company close down with COVID-19. I keep losing money. Because my trade hit SL constantly. Also the profit is very little when there is some. I lost more money than I make right now

Comment: But I’m pretty sure if I modify those coding I will be able to make money. If I have to pay someone to do it for me. I will (the regex coding). This question here. Was more help then anything else. But I guess this is not your concern ‍♂️ If you will ask help in my job Industry and I will be a master on it and of course it will cost me nothing to help you. I will do it because if we don’t help each other who will do? It was very nice talking to you Barmar. Have a blessing day.

Comment: Sorry Barmar, I delete my comment and repost it because of miss spelling your name. Actually auto correction did it not me. Sorry again

Comment: @jesusmendosa ... how about providing the exact result for any exactly provided input/Signal value?

Comment: Use `@` before a name and then use the autocomplete. But I got your message because I'm the only commenter so it automatically went to me.

Comment: Basically Peter, what I’m trying to do. I’m using the system now since 12 months. And I saw that my SL been hit quite all The time. So depending on the signal. BUY or SELL. I will have to move -0,3% or 0,3% UP or DOWN. I want to put percentage because if 0,3% or not enough i can all the time move up the numbers. Same things for TP.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, to come back to me . Let me try to write the code. 

Comment: So basically it will be this right?? /replacerx ⬆️ BUY @SL[0-9] @SLs/~[0-9]*/$0,3%/g

Comment: @jesusmendosa ... I'm not in trading. I do not know any technical terms. Unless it's not really necessary spare me with the details. Programmers are usually good in pattern recognition. Just tell us which result you expect from which input value. Provide as view as possible examples which nevertheless do cover the full possible range. Then one  might see a pattern. Alternatively you could also try to explain yourself or the core problem to the point by using less words for a more precise description.

Comment: Got it! Peter,

The software that I bought provide me signal. When to buy (ENTRY) and when to sell (TP)
It give me also what what we call in trading stop loss (SL) it’s if the trades go wrong it’s when the trade will close.(emergency sell).

Now let’s say The signal giving is:

Signal :⬆️ BUY 
ENTRY: 0.73534 
TP1: 0.76639 
SL: 0.73415

I put on my regex: (I add @ base on my last conversation with Barmar)

/replacerx ⬆️ BUY @SL[0-9] @SLs/~[0-9]*/$0,3%/g

See next comment!!

Comment: If the signal was “SELL” I will put 

Signal :⬇️ SELL 
ENTRY: 0.73534 
TP1: 0.76639 
SL: 0.73415

My regex will be:
/replacerx ⬇️ SELL @SL[0-9] @SLs/~[0-9]*/$-0,3%/g


Now as an example:
Signal BUY 
(SL) = 0.73415 + 0,3%= 0.73635

My new signal will be 0.73635

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```js
const signalList = [
  'Signal :⬆️ BUY Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬆️ BUY Price ENTRY: 0.73534 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬆️ BUY Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639',
  'Signal :⬇️ SELL Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬇️ SELL Price ENTRY: 0.73534 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬇️ SELL Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639',
];
// // [https://regex101.com/r/OK9XKT/1/]
// const regXSignal =
//  (/(?<signal>Signal\s*\:\W+)(?<action>BUY|SELL)(?<entry>\D+[\d.]+)(?<takeprofit>\s+TP\d*\:\s*[\d.]+)?(?<stoploss>\s+SL\d*\:\s*[\d.]+)?/);

// [https://regex101.com/r/OK9XKT/2/]
const regXSignal =
  (/(Signal\s*\:\W+)(BUY|SELL)(\D+[\d.]+)(\s+TP\d*\:\s*[\d.]+)?(\s+SL\d*\:\s*[\d.]+)?/);

function substituteSignalValues(_, signal, action, entry, takeprofit, stoploss) {
  const isSell = (action.toUpperCase() === 'SELL');
  const isBuy = (action.toUpperCase() === 'BUY');
  // takeprofit = (takeprofit && (
  //   (isSell && (takeprofit + ' + 7%')) ||
  //   (isBuy && (takeprofit + ' - 2%')) ||
  //   stoploss
  // ));
  debugger;
  stoploss = (stoploss && (
    (isSell && (stoploss + ' - 0,3%')) ||
    (isBuy && (stoploss + ' + 0,3%')) ||
    stoploss
  ));
  const substitutes = [signal, action, entry];

  if (takeprofit) {
    substitutes.push(takeprofit);
  }
  if (stoploss) {
    substitutes.push(stoploss);
  }
  return substitutes.join('');
}

console.log(
  signalList.map(signal => signal.replace(regXSignal, substituteSignalValues))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

### Edit

As far as my current understanding of the OP's matter does reach, especially for how [`replacerx` might get utilized](https://www.quickmacros.com/help/str/IDP_S_REPLACERX.html), there will be no generic regex/approach for solving the problem. One has to come up with two specific expressions each targeting the specific case of either `SELL` or `BUY` ...

- `SELL` ... [`/(.*SELL)(.*ENTRY\D+[\d.]+)(\s+TP\d*\D+[\d.]+)(\s+SL\d*\D+[\d.]+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/OK9XKT/6)

  - The matches are

    - `$1` ... the `SELL` specific substring
    - `$2` ... the `ENTRY`  specific substring terminated by a number value (which one later could add to some custom data)
    - `$3` ... the `TP` (take profit) specific substring terminated by a number value (which one later could add to some custom data)
    - `$4` ... the `SL` (stop loss) specific substring terminated by a number value (which one later could add to some custom data)
- `BUY` ... [`/(.*BUY)(.*ENTRY\D+[\d.]+)(\s+TP\d*\D+[\d.]+)(\s+SL\d*\D+[\d.]+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/OK9XKT/7)

  - The matches are

    - `$1` ... the `BUY` specific substring
    - `$2` ... the `ENTRY`  specific substring terminated by a number value (which one later could add to some custom data)
    - `$3` ... the `TP` (take profit) specific substring terminated by a number value (which one later could add to some custom data)
    - `$4` ... the `SL` (stop loss) specific substring terminated by a number value (which one later could add to some custom data)

Thus, the OP needs to replace twice, once for each of both actions `SELL` or `BUY` ...

```
s.replacerx("(.*SELL)(.*ENTRY\D+[\d.]+)(\s+TP\d*\D+[\d.]+)(\s+SL\d*\D+[\d.]+)" "$1$2$3$4 - 0,3%")

s.replacerx("(.*BUY)(.*ENTRY\D+[\d.]+)(\s+TP\d*\D+[\d.]+)(\s+SL\d*\D+[\d.]+)" "$1$2$3$4 0,3%")
```

https://docs.junction.space/replace/#Replace_with_regular_expressions

Comment: Target language : English. 
I have to put all these on My regex DOT?

Comment: I thought it would be 1 or 2 coding sentence max.

Comment: I try to copy and paste on DOT but didn’t work. Message error:

“I don`t see any command. Your message should start with a symbol /replacerx and a command. You can see the list of available commands here: /help.
(JOIN_NO_COMMAND: const signalList = [
  'Signal :⬆️ BUY Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬆️ BUY Price ENTRY: 0.73534 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬆️ BUY Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639',
  'Signal :⬇️ SELL Price ENTRY: 0.73534 TP1: 0.76639 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬇️ SELL Price ENTRY: 0.73534 SL: 0.73415',
  'Signal :⬇️ SELL Price ENTRY: …….

Comment: @jesusmendosa ... With target language I meant the programming language or better the runtime environment. It was not clear since the tag-list features e.g. `javascript`, `python`, `telegram-bot`. Your environment seems very specific. Searching for `replacerx`, the most related matches all point to *"Quick Macros - automation software for Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10"*. Thus, unless we are not provided with all the data necessary for solving the problem, there might be no further help/support.

Comment: I don’t know Peter i’m just related to what the message error telling. Like I said I’m not a computer guy. And couldn’t tell you if it is XP vista

Comment: I am already amaze by what I’m doing right now  I know for you guys it’s a peanuts it’s for me I never been so deep in the computer.

Comment: @jesusmendosa did you already have a look into my last ***Edit*** where I boil down, what I think might be (close to) a solution, 2 regular expressions, one `SELL` specific the other `BUY` specific and also show how to concatenate each a custom replacement string?

Comment: Thank you Peter, I just saw you Edit! I will try it and let you know 

Comment: Hello Peter, I did try copy and paste the coding you provide me. Unfortunately it didn’t work. I was talking to somebody else and show him your code. He did tell me to try to separate entry TP and SL to see if that work. Which I did. But still nothing. I feel stuck. I really appreciate your effort. Thank you my friend for trying. God bless you

Comment: @jesusmendosa As I already described it in the last edit / final approach of the above answer; ENTRY, TP and SL are already separated each with its assigned value. There  are even 2 links to a regex playground where it is demonstrated how one does separate a signal into `$1`(SELL/BUY),`$2`(ENTRY),`$3`(TP),`$4`(SL) as well as how one does concatenate them again together with additional data/string values. I'm sorry, there is nothing more that can be done from my side. Try to find someone that maybe understands better the provided approaches and also actually can directly play with your system.